# Authentication using Facebook C# SDK

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

How can I authenticate with a username(email) and password?  The samples provided just calls "authorizer.Authorize()" without credentials (which simply throws an "Invalid URI" format exception for me).  Do I need an accessToken and if so, how do I get one?

Answer (score 5):

You cannot authenticate with a username and password. You must use OAuth to authenticate a user. Facebook does not permit application developers to collect usernames and password from users.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I'm not collecting usernames and passwords.  I already have the usernames and passwords and want to run reports for my clients.  You helped me before with the reporting issue and I appreciate it but I ran into a problem with the code because I wasn't authenticated.  There must be a way to do this with OAuth then.  I just need to tie in the account (I only have username/password) with OAuth somehow.  Is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

This tutorial should help you: [Getting Started with the Facebook C# SDK](http://multitiered.wordpress.com/2010/08/05/getting-started-with-the-facebook-c-sharp-sdk/)

Comment: Thanks but I saw this and it doesn't explain how to use username/password.  :(

Comment: Would this be what you're looking for then? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ee702803

Comment: Totally lost now.  I need an application key and secret key now?  Where does the user account fit in so I can get/set the right data?

Comment: That guide refers to an SDK which has been depreciated.

Comment: @Phil They no longer are supporting the C# SDK, nor will they in the future. I'm not sure if this is still kept up though: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ee388574

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do exactly.  But here is my experience and my knowledge of authentication.

In order to authenticate a user, you need a facebook application (specifically app id and server code), the user has to input their username and password and allows your app to access their data.

This authorization process will generate an access token that will your facebook app to access the user info.  Note that this access_token expires often and in which case you need to authenticate again.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Answer (score 0):

Follow this youtube link and you might understand how you will get authenticated using ur website.
this will redirect you to facebook where you have to log in, so if you want a random user on ur site to authenticate they will be redirected to facebook log in if u use the code from this example:

[Facebook Auth Example](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IsO0G-8idyo)

Hope this is what your looking for m8!