# Using Facebook for authentication into websites

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook-c#-sdk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Authentication using Facebook C# SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610087/authentication-using-facebook-c-sdk)

I want to use facebook authentication into my website and I did look into the facebook c# API and was not able to get through this. Can any one help with these and how this authentication works I need to get their email id once authenticated.

Thanks

Comment: Look into oauth 2.0 http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Comment: Have you bothered to read the documentation?

Comment: Found the solution http://area72.ro/programming/using-regex-to-extract-content-between-html-tags.html this was really helpful