# how to login to facebook with c# without the facebook page

Tags: c#

I am pretty new at programming. I saw many examples on how to c# login to facebook, all of them are using the facebook login page to login. my question is how do I pass the username and the password form my own text box I create and my own login button. is it possible ?

Comment: There are some good resources here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610087/authentication-using-facebook-c-sharp-sdk and here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure you can't do this.

The only way to authenticate with Facebook is via a Facebook login page.

If Facebook allowed login via 3rd party forms, there would be nothing to stop malicious sites from collecting Facebook login details.

Comment: You actually can do this, but for the reasons you mention, it is not really something you'd want to do in a production app at all.  I've also seen desktop apps like Picasa that have the ability to upload photos to a user's account(although the user must Approve the photos before they appear), so there actually is some sort of approved API for desktop apps to integrate with Facebook, but I have never figured out how to do that.

Comment: I guess then facebook login it is.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you are trying to accomplish.  There are some integration API's for Facebook if you have a site that you want to integrate with Facebook.

The only way I've found to login directly from a desktop app, is by using a WebBrowser class, requesting the facebook login page, then populating the username/password fields programmatically:
`webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("textName").SetAttribute("value") = "ddddd" ;`

The result of the login will produce several cookies that identify the session, and you can transfer those into a HttpWebRequest so that you requests will be seen as logged in.

Like Rik said, this is a **very bad practice** because you'd have to collect user details through your own form, (although you could always display the WebBrowser window directly to the user, you are still asking them to do something very risky because the application hosting the WebBrowser class can intercept the login information).

Comment: Not only is it a very bad practice, doing anything to bypass the web page is a violation of the TOS of almost every API that implements OAuth (showing the webpage is part of the OAuth standard). ***If Facebook finds out you are bypassing the login page your application key will be revoked and then your program will suddenly stop working for all of your users.***

Comment: @Scott This request is not coming from a facebook app, and it does not use the OAuth api.  There is no application key required, thus none to be revoked.  The WebBrowser class is an IE user agent and it appears from the server side as a user logging in directly to the site.

Comment: @Scott But indeed, for all the reasons you mention, and as I've said, this is not the approach you'd take in any kind of production application.

Comment: @Scott It is alot of fun though, if you want to automate some things on your own Facebook account though.